# How to update a value in a delta table column in Azure Databricks with Map of Struct datatype?

Tags: arrays, struct, azure-databricks

I have a delta table in Databricks named `prod.silver.control_table`. It has a few columns including `table_name` with string data type and `transform_options` with below structure:

```
 |-- transform_options: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: struct (valueContainsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- col_name_mappings: map (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- key: string
 |    |    |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- type_mappings: map (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- key: string
 |    |    |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- partition_duplicates_by: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- order_duplicates_by: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

For example, when `table_name` is `prod.silver.weather`, the `transform_options` is:

```
{
"prod.bronze.weather_source_a":{"col_name_mappings":{"col_a_old":"col_a_new","col_b_old":"col_b_new"},"type_mappings":{"col_a_new":"INT","col_b_new":"TIMESTAMP"},"partition_duplicates_by":["col_a_new"],"order_duplicates_by":["_commit_version"]},
"prod.bronze.weather_source_b":{"col_name_mappings":{"col_c_old":"col_c_new","col_d_old":"col_d_new"},"type_mappings":{"col_c_new":"INT","col_d_new":"TIMESTAMP"},"partition_duplicates_by":["col_c_new"],"order_duplicates_by":["ingestion_timestamp","_commit_version"]}
}
```

I need to update values in `order_duplicates_by`. I need to change `_commit_version` into `commit_version` by removing the initial underscore.

In the above example, there are 2 key-value pairs in the `transform_options` column. It is not always the case and there might be only one key-value pair.

Any idea how to update table values?

Note that I want to update values in the control table. I prefer to use the SQL command like below however if there is a better way, please let me know:

```
UPDATE prod.silver.control_table
SET ...
```

I tried the below code:

```
UPDATE prod.silver.control_table
SET transform_options = 
    MAP(
        /* I iterate through each key-value pair in the original map */
        TRANSFORM_KEYS(transform_options, key -> key),
        TRANSFORM_VALUES(transform_options, (key, value) -> 
            /* then I create a new struct with updated order_duplicates_by */
            STRUCT(
                value.col_name_mappings AS col_name_mappings,
                value.type_mappings AS type_mappings,
                value.partition_duplicates_by AS partition_duplicates_by,
                /* Here I replace '_commit_version' with 'commit_version' in the array */
                TRANSFORM(value.order_duplicates_by, item -> 
                    CASE WHEN item = '_commit_version' THEN 'commit_version' ELSE item END
                ) AS order_duplicates_by
            )
        )
    )
WHERE table_name = 'prod.silver.weather';
```

But get an error:

```
com.databricks.backend.common.rpc.SparkDriverExceptions$SQLExecutionException: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: [INVALID_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_CALL.NUM_ARGS_MISMATCH]
    Invalid lambda function call. A higher order function expects 1 arguments, but got 2.; line 5 pos 42
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the code below to perform such transformations.

```sql
SELECT 
    table_name,
    transform_values(transform_options, (k, v) -> 
    case
    when array_contains(v.order_duplicates_by, '_commit_version') then
    STRUCT(v.col_name_mappings, v.type_mappings, v.partition_duplicates_by, array_append(array_remove(v.order_duplicates_by, '_commit_version'), 'commit_version') as order_duplicates_by)
    else
     STRUCT(v.col_name_mappings, v.type_mappings, v.partition_duplicates_by, v.order_duplicates_by)
    end
    ) AS updated_transform_options
FROM control_table
```

Here, using the `transform_values` function, I am getting map keys and values and checking if `_commit_version` is present.
If it is present, then remove and append the required string; otherwise, leave the old values.

Output:

| table_name | updated_transform_options |
| --- | --- |
| prod.silver.weather | {"prod.bronze.weather_source_a":{"col_name_mappings":{"col_a_old":"col_a_new","col_b_old":"col_b_new"},"type_mappings":{"col_a_new":"INT","col_b_new":"TIMESTAMP"},"partition_duplicates_by":["col_a_new"],"order_duplicates_by":["commit_version"]}} |
| prod.silver.other_table | {"prod.bronze.weather_source_b":{"col_name_mappings":{"col_x_old":"col_x_new","col_y_old":"col_y_new"},"type_mappings":{"col_x_new":"STRING","col_y_new":"DATE"},"partition_duplicates_by":["col_x_new"],"order_duplicates_by":["ingestion_timestamp","commit_version"]}} |

Updated code:

```sql
update control_table 
set transform_options = transform_values(
  transform_options, (k, v) -> 
    case
    when array_contains(v.order_duplicates_by, '_commit_version') then
    STRUCT(v.col_name_mappings, v.type_mappings, v.partition_duplicates_by, array_append(array_remove(v.order_duplicates_by, '_commit_version'), 'commit_version') as order_duplicates_by)
    else
     STRUCT(v.col_name_mappings, v.type_mappings, v.partition_duplicates_by, v.order_duplicates_by)
    end
    )
```

Comment: Thanks. Does it return 2 rows? Note that the above sample value is only for one row in the control table. Also, I want to update values in the table not returning the values. Perhaps, need to use the UPDATE command.

Comment: I used `when` and `then` to check condition for not having values and having values. If you want use update statement you need to set the column value.so you need to access order_duplicates_by fiield which is list and need to check _commit_version also.

Comment: Accessing those values of map type doesn't really update the values.

Comment: I think the above code returns a table, but I want to update the existing table. It seems that it returns 2 rows for the sample value in the question. However, there is only one row in the control table (one row for the prod.silver.weather which contains two "_commit_version").

Comment: I know which rows have "_commit_versoin" in the control table, so checking might not be required. Could you please help to construct the UPDATE SET command?

Comment: I will update you?

Comment: I tried to use UPDATE SET to update the table but couldn't construct the correct function. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @Mohammad I have added the updated code. Kindly check it

Comment: Thanks. It works. Could you please help me once more to write a code to return only rows where "order_duplicates_by" contains "_commit_version" I used this code but it returns all rows from table: SELECT *, transform_values(transform_options, (k, v) -> CASE WHEN array_contains(v.order_duplicates_by, '_commit_version') THEN STRUCT(v.col_name_mappings, v.type_mappings, v.partition_duplicates_by, v.order_duplicates_by) ELSE NULL END ) AS updated_transform_options FROM dev.silver.test_silver_control_table;

Comment: in else part give `null` and filter based on it.

Comment: I tried so, but could not create the correct query. Could you help me by providing the whole query?